# Is there a way to change the value used for State within OpenID for .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

Is it possible within .NET Core to change the "state" value which is sent to a client's autorization endpoint? As far as I am aware I do not have control over this value.

For some context, I have a client who has advised that they cannot accept a state longer than 255 characters, yet the .NET Core Middleware handles the state value completely and appears to generate a random string longer than 800 characters from my test scenario.

Apologies if this is an odd question. Thanks!

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to set custom state in `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` hook, like this:

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (RedirectContext context) => {
  context.ProtocolMessage.State = "CUSTOM_STATE";
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```